# Which kernel is this

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics

If $x \sim N(0,\sigma^{2})$ and

$\pi(\sigma)=\frac{1}{\sigma}exp(\frac{-a}{\sigma^{2}})$

then the posterior would be proportional to

As,

$f(x|\sigma)$ proportional to $\frac{1}{\sigma}exp(\frac{-x^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}})$

$$\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}exp[\frac{-(x^2+2a)}{2\sigma^{2}}]$$

what kernel is this?

I know that the posterior exists because it integrates numerically.

From  *The Bayesian Choice*

The author notes posterior exists for all x. Which as I stated is true form numerically checking the integral. But I want to know how I could see this if I could not have checked numerically, ie from a known kernel or such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I have not checked your working; indeed I have relied on it being correct)

Considered in terms of $\sigma$ it should be a scaled inverse chi (with $\nu=1$).

The inverse chi has density $$f(x) \propto x^{-\nu-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2x^2}},\,x>0,\,\nu>0\,.$$

Let $Y=X/\theta$ and you should be able to reproduce what you have for a particular choice of $\theta$.

Considered as a posterior for $\sigma^2$ it looks like it'd be a limiting case of the inverse gamma, as the shape parameter goes to zero (which isn't a proper density).

Comment: Which work are you reffering to? I just multiply the normal by that prior given ( tried to update to show) and Yes I thought of inverse gamma with zero but then I  remebered that parameter for inv gamma must be greater then 0

Comment: You did a bit more than that since you also said that you showed it was integrable.

Comment: Ah , i see what you mean. I just mean I plugged it into wolfram and got a real result.

Comment: But would saying it is a limit case of gamma be a valid argument for its existence? Or is that not in general sufficient? But that chi square part seems to look right , i guess the numerator of the exponential multiplies out so we can ignore

Comment: It would be more an argument for it being an improper posterior distribution. The numerator would be taken up by the scaling factor I suggested; indeed that was the point of referring to a *scaled* inverse chi in the first place.

Comment: I mean the $exp(-(x^{2}+a^{2})$ but that could factor out

Comment: $x^2 + 2a$ is  a constant. Why would you try to "factor" anything? As I said it's taken up by the scale parameter.

Comment: Because if i wanted to find the result of integrating the marginal(although this would be a seprate question to just showing it exists), for example in a gamma, it may have appeared as the beta parameter (over 2) ( but I realise you could just bring outside integral so thanks for your answer, I will just wait to see if anyone else or author has any other comment on it)

Comment: You can't just "bring it outside the integral" for $\sigma$. Its square root is a scaling factor on $\sigma$. In relation to some other parameter, you can pull it out of an integral if you can pull the whole term with $\sigma$ out.

Comment: @Xi'an is inverse chi what you were looking to notice?

Comment: I'm puzzled by the @ for Xi'an there ... did he comment here?

Comment: no, he wrote the question (as I said in the post it was from his book)

Comment: He won't see your @ -- it only works for people that have participated on the thread in some way